# Нужны ли кавычки (2)?

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки

`(«)Нет(») всегда можно превратить в («)да(»).`

Как думаете, совы?

Comment: Максим, опять чужими словами пользуетесь. Называется нас лучше филинами или еще как.

Comment: @Sharon Я давно уже это слово использовал.

Comment: @Sharon К тому же вы тоже один раз это слово использовали, а это слово Леопольда)) Так же я по его принципу стал оформлять сообщения в виде кода, только он после этого цитированием оформляет, хотя я как бы не запрещае ему дальше код использовать. Да и я хотя бы не _совчонки_ говорю, то есть не копирую полностью))

Comment: Я использовала   это слово  в ироническом смысле: все совы тогда разлетелись и помочь мне никак не хотели) У меня же есть вопросы к оформлению ваших тем. Какие? Да много всего: (1) Слишком свободный/разговорный стиль (сов и филинов надо решительно изгонять). (2) Заголовок не передает суть вопроса. (3) Не соблюдаются общие правила: обозначение проблемы, ваши поиски решения.  И это при том, что по содержанию они интересны, но желательна более строгая запись и четкое обозначение вашего предварительного решения.  (4) Поспешное принятие ответов.Но у вас хороший потенциал, можно все это исправить.